# Makefile increase variable on each build

Tags: bash, shell, makefile, gnu-make

I've a makefile with variable `DOCKER_TAG = 0.0.1`

and I want that on each target called it will be bumped (only patch version ) is it possible

e.g.

```
DOCKER_TAG = 0.0.1

push: 
    docker push docker.io/testasm:$(DOCKER_TAG)
```

now If I run `make push` it will use version `0.0.1` but If I do it for the second time it will be bumped to `0.0.2` and so on (on each run of `make push`) , is it possible ?

**update** I've tried the following

```
DOCKER_TAG = 0.0.1
DOCKER_REGISTRY = testreg/vsp


VERSION_FILE   := version.txt
-include $(VERSION_FILE)

VERMAJMIN      := $(subst ., ,$(DOCKER_TAG))

DOCKER_TAG     := $(shell [ -f "$(VERSION_FILE)" ] && cat "$(VERSION_FILE)" || echo '0.0.1')
VERMAJMIN      := $(subst ., ,$(DOCKER_TAG))
VERSION        := $(word 1,$(VERMAJMIN))
MAJOR          := $(word 2,$(VERMAJMIN))
MINOR          := $(word 3,$(VERMAJMIN))
NEW_MINOR      := $(shell expr "$(MINOR)" + 1)
NEW_DOCKER_TAG := $(VERSION).$(MAJOR).$(NEW_MINOR)



NEW_DOCKER_TAG := $(VERSION).$(MAJOR).$(NEW_MINOR)


build:
    echo "$(NEW_DOCKER_TAG)" > "$(VERSION_FILE)"
```

And the `version.txt` file get value of `..` two dots ... any idea how to solve it?

if I take the last option in the answer **as-is**
I see that the `version.txt` file contain `DOCKER_TAG := ..`

**update 2**

I've created empty version.txt file and use the folloing as-is

```
VERSION_FILE   := version.txt
DOCKER_TAG     := 0.0.1.

-include $(VERSION_FILE)

VERMAJMIN      := $(subst ., ,$(DOCKER_TAG))

NEW_DOCKER_TAG := $(VERSION).$(MAJOR).$(NEW_MINOR)
build:
    docker build -t docker.io/vcd/test:$(DOCKER_TAG) .
    echo "DOCKER_TAG := $(NEW_DOCKER_TAG)" > "$(VERSION_FILE)"
```

and I got in the version.txt file the following `DOCKER_TAG := ..`

Comment: Do you know how to do this without make? I mean, how to use `docker` commands to get the current version number, and how to use the shell to increment it?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet -  is there a way im make to take a var value like 0.0.1 and when you run some target to update it ,something like `push: updversion` and increment only the last value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best would be to use some docker command (`docker search`?) to query the repository and get the last version from there. In case it is not possible you can store it in a text file, read it each time you run make, and update it. Something like:

```
VERSION_FILE   := version.txt
DOCKER_TAG     := $(shell [ -f "$(VERSION_FILE)" ] && cat "$(VERSION_FILE)" || echo '0.0.1')
VERMAJMIN      := $(subst ., ,$(DOCKER_TAG))
VERSION        := $(word 1,$(VERMAJMIN))
MAJOR          := $(word 2,$(VERMAJMIN))
MINOR          := $(word 3,$(VERMAJMIN))
NEW_MINOR      := $(shell expr "$(MINOR)" + 1)
NEW_DOCKER_TAG := $(VERSION).$(MAJOR).$(NEW_MINOR)

push:
    docker push docker.io/testasm:$(DOCKER_TAG)
    echo "$(NEW_DOCKER_TAG)" > "$(VERSION_FILE)"
```

Of course you will have to take care of your version file and avoid accidental deletion. For higher security you could write the first version file yourself and instruct make to raise an error in case the file does not exist:

```
VERSION_FILE   := version.txt

ifneq ($(wildcard $(VERSION_FILE)),$(VERSION_FILE))

$(error $(VERSION_FILE) not found)

else

DOCKER_TAG     := $(shell cat "$(VERSION_FILE)")
VERMAJMIN      := $(subst ., ,$(DOCKER_TAG))
VERSION        := $(word 1,$(VERMAJMIN))
MAJOR          := $(word 2,$(VERMAJMIN))
MINOR          := $(word 3,$(VERMAJMIN))
NEW_MINOR      := $(shell expr "$(MINOR)" + 1)
NEW_DOCKER_TAG := $(VERSION).$(MAJOR).$(NEW_MINOR)

push:
    docker push docker.io/testasm:$(DOCKER_TAG)
    echo "$(NEW_DOCKER_TAG)" > "$(VERSION_FILE)"

endif
```

Variant where the version file is itself a Makefile included by the main one:

```
VERSION_FILE   := version.txt
DOCKER_TAG     := 0.0.1

-include $(VERSION_FILE)

VERMAJMIN      := $(subst ., ,$(DOCKER_TAG))
VERSION        := $(word 1,$(VERMAJMIN))
MAJOR          := $(word 2,$(VERMAJMIN))
MINOR          := $(word 3,$(VERMAJMIN))
NEW_MINOR      := $(shell expr "$(MINOR)" + 1)
NEW_DOCKER_TAG := $(VERSION).$(MAJOR).$(NEW_MINOR)

push:
    docker push docker.io/testasm:$(DOCKER_TAG)
    echo "DOCKER_TAG := $(NEW_DOCKER_TAG)" > "$(VERSION_FILE)"
```

(remove the `-` on front of `-include $(VERSION_FILE)` to get an error if the file does not exist. This last one is my favorite.

Comment: Thanks! I tried the lastone and when I run it I got error `version.txt:1: *** missing separator.  Stop.
` I've create a file `version.txt` sibling to the makefile and put there value `0.0.1` , do I miss something ?

Comment: when I remove the value from the `txt` file and run `make push` It works but new value is added to to the file `DOCKER_TAG := ..`

Comment: You merged two solutions. If you use the `include $(VERSION_FILE)` solution the `echo`command is `echo "DOCKER_TAG := $(NEW_DOCKER_TAG)" > "$(VERSION_FILE)"` not `echo "$(NEW_DOCKER_TAG)" > "$(VERSION_FILE)"`. Chose one or the other but do not mix them together. And your first problem was probably due to spaces instead of tabs. In the solutions I show all indented lines should be indented with one tab, not with spaces.

Comment: Please see my update 2, I've tried the last option and the version.txt file contain `DOCKER_TAG := ..` value, any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Oh! I see. You did not replace the `...` ellipsis I used to not repeat identical lines. Sorry, this was not clear enough. I edited my answer to remove the ellipsis. Try to copy-paste exactly the last solution, in each indented line replace the leading spaces by a tab, and **be careful**, it is `DOCKER_TAG := 0.0.1`, not `DOCKER_TAG := 0.0.1.` (no trailing dot).

Comment: thank you! I try the last option and I got error: `expr: not a decimal number: '' any idea? does it works for you?
`

Comment: when I change the order and put the following `VERSION_FILE   := version.txt
DOCKER_TAG     := 0.0.1` after the `-include file` the file now contain `DOCKER_TAG := 0.0.2` , which is great however when I run it for the second time it doesnt updated ...

Comment: Yes, I just copy-pasted exactly the last solution, replaced the leading spaces by a tab, ran make and I got exactly what is expected. I suspect a typo. And no, you cannot swap line randomly. For instance if you define `VERSION_FILE` after using it in `-include $(VERSION_FILE)` things will go wrong.